What is the stack trace for the gack Id Gack ID: 1850279669-328180 (1487738890)?
What is the stack trace for the gack Id  Gack ID: 1850279669-328180 (1487738890)?
When I try to publish the Embedded Service Deployment, I receive this error


This is the response I have got from SF Support
PublishConnectAPI``0`1``common.sql.OracleRowLockedException: common.exception.SfdcSqlException: ERROR: canceling statement due to lock timeout

Where: SQL statement "SELECT /*Site.sql(586fd1f):lock_site_row_nc:158*/ s.site_id

FROM sitedev.site AS s

WHERE s.organization_id = iOrganizationId

AND s.site_id = iSiteId

FOR NO KEY UPDATE OF s WAIT 10"

PL/sdb function grumpy.site.lock_site_row_nc(character varying,character varying) line 8 (SFSQL 158) at SQL statement

 

SQLException while executing plsql statement: {call Site.lock_site_row_nc(?,?)}(00D00000000SBID, 0DM00000000Oesd)

